# Mocking external API for unit testing in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I spend now some hours for searching a library for mocking an external api in nodejs. I already tried the SinonJS library, but it seems not to work for external web calls... Does anybody know another library which allows the mocking of external web calls? Or do somebody have a working example for SinonJS?

Thank you for every answer!

Below you can find my code.

My Unit Test with SinonJS:

```
import expect from 'expect';
import { searchForProducts } from 'api/ProductAPI';
import emptyResults from 'api/ProductAPI_EmptyResult.json';

describe('ProductAPI', () => {
  let server;

  before(function () {
    server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    server.respondWith(
      "GET",
      "https://my.domain.com/myresource",
      [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, JSON.stringify(emptyResults)]
    );
  });

  it('product search with working API ', () => {

    server.respond();

    searchForProducts('tv').then(
      (data) => {
        console.log('success');
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('error');
      });

    //dummy expect
    expect(
      'test'
    ).toEqual('test');

  });
});
```

ProductAPI:

```
import restClient from './RestClient';

/**
 *
 * Returns a list of products 
 * @param query
 * @returns {ProductDTOs}
 */
function _searchForProducts(query) {
  return restClient().get(
    `/myresource`
  );
}
```

RestClient (with Axios):

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const restClient = function restClient() {
  let axios;
  let apiUrl;

  function _url(url) {
    return `${apiUrl}${url}`;
  }

  function _get(url) {
    return axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: _url(url),
    });
  }

  function _post(url, data) {
    return axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: _url(url), data,
    });
  }

  function _put(url, data) {
    return axios({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: _url(url), data,
    });
  }

  function _patch(url, data) {
    return axios({
      method: 'PATCH',
      url: _url(url),
      data,
    });
  }

  function _delete(url, data) {
    return axios({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: _url(url), data,
    });
  }

  function _setDefaultHeaders() {
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  }

  function _setAuthorizationHeader(token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  function _removeAuthorizationHeader() {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '';
  }

  function _setup() {
    axios = Axios;
    apiUrl = 'https://my.domain.com';

    _setDefaultHeaders();
  }

  _setup();

  return {
    setup: _setup,
    url: _url,
    get: _get,
    post: _post,
    put: _put,
    patch: _patch,
    delete: _delete,
    setDefaultHeaders: _setDefaultHeaders,
    setAuthorizationHeader: _setAuthorizationHeader,
    removeAuthorizationHeader: _removeAuthorizationHeader,
  };
};

export default restClient;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Show your code. `sinon` can do all what you need.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I added now my code. The problem is that I don't receive any response from my fake server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem I forgot some server configs. To make the server running I had to set the autoRespond attribute on true:

```
  before(function () {
    server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    server.respondWith(
      "GET",
      "https://ec2-52-58-48-214.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/mspocc/v2/msp/products/search?query=tv&fields=FULL",
      [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, JSON.stringify(emptyResults)]
    );
    server.autoRespond = true
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using spies functionality in sinon or any other test suite like jasmine should be the appropriate way of mocking external calls.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is it possible to create promises with a spies? because the _searchForProducts in ProductAPI is returning a promise. For me it looks a little bit complicated...

Comment: Yes, you can fake a promise: 
    spyOn(Contact, 'retrieveContactInfo').and.callFake(function() {
      return {
        then: function(callback) { return callback(user); }
      };
    });